# cvSetImageROI doesn't seem to be fast enough

Tags: c++, c, opencv, optimization, image-processing

To process a certain region of the image, I use cvSetImageROI and cvResetImageROI.

But It feels like this function itself takes longer than I expected.

Does anybody know about this or have an alternative way to do the same task.

Answer (score 1):

cvSetImageROI and cvResetImageROI are just setting the values of ROI in image header plus do some small conditions checks. This is done in nano-seconds on any computer. If you can measure the time of this operation something is indeed very wrong. Are you 100% that those are the operations that cause slowdown?